# How to Revert Back to original CSS and Html after Jquery hover in Draggable Div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, draggable, jquery-hover

I was wondering how to revert the CSS/Html back to its original state for the 'Drag Me Around' text inside the Draggable Div after the hover function has occurred.

I am a bit of a javascript/jQuery novice as you can tell and have collated my existing code from various sources and I'm trying to make it work around my needs.

The Draggable div uses jQuery UI.

Please click on the jsfiddle link below to examine what I mean better.

https://jsfiddle.net/TEK22/79sgwxm5/28/

```js
 $( function() {
 $( "#what-a-drag" ).draggable();
 } );


 $(".link-img").hover(function(){
 $(".img-show").html($(this).html());
 },
    function() {
 $( ".img-show" ).html( "Drag Me Around - (How to ake this go back to how it was?)" );
 });
```

```css
p {
  width:auto;
}

p img {
  display: none;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px
}

p a {
  font-style: bold;
  text-decoration: underline ;
}

#what-a-drag {
  display: show;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  top: 20%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border: 2.2px solid black;
  color: black;
  cursor: move;
}

#drag-me{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);


  font-family: Helvetica  !important;
  font-weight: 450  !important;
  font-size: 0.9em  !important;
  line-height: 0.2em !important;
  color: black  !important;
  text-align: center  !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="what-a-drag" class="img-show">
<p id="drag-me">Drag Me Around</p>
</div>

<p><a class="link-img"><img src="../">Hover on me </a> to show image in draggable div
</p>







<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what was happened is that when you went over (Hover on me) you were replacing your

```
<p id="drag-me">Drag Me Around</p>
```

with this code

```
$(".img-show").html($(this).html());
```

one way around this is to replace it with this, just add the p, so that you replace the p text instead of the html inside the img-show class.

```
$(".img-show p").html($(this).html());
```

Then to change the text back to what you had it you need to change the last part of the code to this, again just adding the p.

```
$( ".img-show p" ).html( "Drag Me Around" );
```

See code snippet for working example or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9e2hudq/).

```js
 $( function() {
 $( "#what-a-drag" ).draggable();
 } );


 $(".link-img").hover(function(){
 $(".img-show p").html($(this).html());
 },
    function() {
 $( ".img-show p" ).html( "Drag Me Around" );
 });
```

```css
p {
  width:auto;
}

p img {
  display: none;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px
}

p a {
  font-style: bold;
  text-decoration: underline ;
}

#what-a-drag {
  display: show;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  top: 20%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border: 2.2px solid black;
  color: black;
  cursor: move;
}

#drag-me{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);


  font-family: Helvetica  !important;
  font-weight: 450  !important;
  font-size: 0.9em  !important;
  line-height: 0.2em !important;
  color: black  !important;
  text-align: center  !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="what-a-drag" class="img-show">
<p id="drag-me">Drag Me Around</p>
</div>

<p><a class="link-img"><img src="../">Hover on me </a> to show image in draggable div
</p>







<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$( function() {
    $( "#what-a-drag" ).draggable();
} );

var cloneme = $('#drag-me').clone();
$(".link-img").hover(function(){
    $(".img-show").html($(this).html());
  },
  function() {
    $( ".img-show" ).html(cloneme);
  }
);
```

It will take back `Drag Me Around` text

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for! super simple and works perfectly.

Comment: No worries, we are here to give our services to sort out the issues. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to replace the background. But the real element is you want capture the content of the div and then put them back after the hover. This can be done using `.data()`. For example:

```js
$(function() {
  function showImage($target, url) {
    $target.data("original", $target.html());
    $target.html("");
    $target.css("background-image", "url('" + url + "')");
  }

  function hideImage($target) {
    $target.css("background-image", "");
    $target.html($target.data("original"));
  }

  $("#what-a-drag").draggable();
  $(".link-img").hover(function() {
    showImage($("#what-a-drag"), "https://i.imgur.com/ICiQTOV.jpg")
  }, function() {
    hideImage($("#what-a-drag"));
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  width: auto;
}

p img {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

p a {
  font-style: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#what-a-drag {
  display: show;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  top: 20%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border: 2.2px solid black;
  color: black;
  cursor: move;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#drag-me {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: Helvetica !important;
  font-weight: 450 !important;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  line-height: 0.2em !important;
  color: black !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="what-a-drag" class="img-show">
  <p id="drag-me">Drag Me Around</p>
</div>

<p>
  <a class="link-img">Hover on me</a> to show image in draggable div
</p>
```

This, when the hover is in, captures whatever is in the div and stores it. Then on the out, it replaces it back to the div.

I hope that helps.